# How do I make a simple login system using php?

Tags: php, html

I got a task to make a login system using php, specifically one that hashes the password into a .txt file (this isnt how you're suppose to ik that) I've tried and tried but can't figure out how to even start. I've been told to Make an array with the function file(). Would appreciate any kind of help

Have this currently

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    
<form action="test.php" method="post">

<span>Username</span>
<input type="text" name="Username" id="Login-Input-Username" required><br>

<span>Password</span>
<input type="password" name="Password" id="Login-Input-Password" required>

<button type="submit" name="Submit-Button" value="submit" id="Login-
Button">Sign In</button>
</form>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit-Button']))
    {
    $username = $_POST['Username'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $fileRows = file("accounts.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    
    }?>
```

Comment: You can use file_put_contents() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know why you want to store data in a file but you can rewrite your PHP code to look like this

```
<?PHP

if(isset($_POST['Submit-Button']))
    {
    $username = $_POST['Username'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
   
    $data = [
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $hash,
    ];

    $fileRows = file_put_contents('accounts.txt', json_encode($data).PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);    
    }?>
```

Comment: The data I wanna store is the username and the hashed password, so I can make a password_verify

Comment: Yea.. So this stored the hashed password. Did you go through the code I wrote and tested it?

Comment: Wow it does work perfectly fine! Is there a way I can make it so you can't use the same password/username multiple times?

Comment: If it works as you want, then tick my answer as the correct one.

Comment: Yes but I can store the same password multiple times as of rn, is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: There is a way to check that though it is not worth it. You can iterate through all the passwords and check if the hash value equals the new inputted password. So just imagine having thousands of records, you need to reiterate through the whole list of the password which will be inefficient.